# How do I find the ODE in Sturm-Liouville form when given two functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have not had any success in finding the Sturm-Liouville ODE corresponding to the ODE solutions

$\{x^m \cos(nx), x^m  \sin(nx)\}$ where $n,m \in \mathbb {R}$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider

$$(\frac{y}{x^m})’’+n^2 \frac{y}{x^m} = 0.$$

Now, can you put it in Sturm-Liouville form?

Also, I think it makes more sense for $n$ to be an integer.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any intuition behind the guess?

Comment: Yea, there is some intuition. The fact that there are two solutions means that the ODE is order 2. Also, you should try to get it in a form such that the solution involves $\sin ku$ and $\cos ku$. This is achieved using $u’’+k^2u = 0$. Now, obviously we need $k=n$. Also, notice that dividing by $x^m$ works to turn $y$ into $u$